# ExtJS 6 microloader/boostrap.js root path

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs6-modern

In my java web application sources generated by Sencha CMD are located in resources folder. I am trying to run application in dev mode (without build) using boostrap.js, so I declared Ext.Manifest and included below in jsp file:

`<script id="microloader" data-app="52906e0a-6b39-4de6-b1f2-dc27cf37969e" type="text/javascript" src="resources/bootstrap.js"></script>`

With standard configuration microloader tries to load files as if extjs application source files were directly in web root path, which is inccorect as the files are not there:

`http://localhost:8080/myapp/classic.json`

how to "tell" microloader to look for the files in resource folder, so the request would look like this:

`http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/classic.json`

I am able to make this work without using boostrap.js, if I include app.js directly and specify appFolder in Ext.Application. But I want to test different profiles (modern, classic).

Comment: I think you can set this up in the somewhere in app.json

Comment: The best config I found that should do the trick is boostrap.base in app.json but it is not working. When I set `"base": "resources/${app.dir}"` it still tries to load classic.json from web root.

Comment: After changes to the app.json I think you have to rebuild the bootstrap.

Comment: After changing base I cannot build application. SenchaCmd throws error that is unable to find bootstrap.js in `..\webapp\resources\resources`. Note that I already generated app in resources folder.

Comment: In Extjs6 when building prod it will put the entire bootstrap.json in local storage. We had similar issues. Clear the Local storage.

Comment: @gisit you will have to make entry in app.json for "path"

Comment: @Couponrabais there is nothing in local storage

Comment: @Tejas1991 where to add path? In root level of app.json add `"path":"resources/"`?

Comment: yes inside path

Comment: do you find a solution ? i m asking questions in same theme here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634461/stack-extjs-6-spring-boot

Comment: No. I ended up developing without boostrap.js. There was a similar question regarding extjs 5 also without answer https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286393-How-to-set-correct-paths-in-the-generated-bootstrap-json